# Vagrant docker provisioner and provider not using cmd: option

Tags: vagrant, docker, vagrantfile

I have Vagrant 1.6.5 and Docker version 1.3.2.

If i use either the Docker provider or provisioner, i am unable to override the CMD with my own.

Example provider config i tried:

```
config.vm.provider :docker do |d|
   d.image = 'ubuntu'
   d.remains_running = true
   d.has_ssh = false
   d.ports = ["8080:8080"]
   d.volumes = ["/tmp/:/tmp"]
   d.cmd = ["ping", "-c 50", "127.0.0.1"]
end
```

Example provisoner config i tried:

```
config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.run "ubuntu",
    args: '-v /tmp:/tmp -p 2222:22',
    cmd: "/bin/sh -c 'ping -c 10 127.0.0.1; touch /tmp/hello_world'"
end
```

This is the Dockerfile that the official Ubuntu Docker registry uses to build from:

https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/b3d5822d7fa42d27cbf32e5fcc0b97b02c007618/trusty/Dockerfile

When i run vagrant, the docker container always exists immediately and the output of `docker ps -a` always just shows the command to be that which is specified in the ubuntu Dockerfile.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
bb6922063bfe        ubuntu:14.04        "/bin/bash"            12 minutes ago      Exited (0) 6 seconds ago                            root_default_1417660734
```

Am i missing something? I should be able to use the Ubuntu image and override the CMD options with my own to run arbitrary commands i think?

thanks
fLo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Vagrant 1.6.5 and Docker 1.3.1 and this Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider :docker do |d|
     d.image = 'ubuntu'
     d.remains_running = true
     d.has_ssh = false
     d.ports = ["8080:8080"]
     d.volumes = ["/tmp/:/tmp"]
     d.cmd = ["ping", "-c 51", "127.0.0.1"]
  end
end
```

with the following command:

```
vagrant up --provider=docker
```

My Output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
700bea5ec611        ubuntu:latest       "ping '-c 50' 127.0.   5 minutes ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   vagrant_default_1417725827
```

Everything works fine for me with this command. FYI I usr Docker with [non-root access](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#giving-non-root-access)